# Fiber Photometry (Fluorescence) Signal Preprocessing through Source Separation and Baseline Correction

Tags: filters, signal-analysis, source-separation, preprocessing

I am working on preprocessing fiber photometry data. The data collection involves inserting fibers into an animal, where the reflection of specific wavelengths of light is captured. We collect two types of signals: an experimental signal (which contains both the true signal and noise) and a control signal (which contains various types of noise, such as movement noise, photobleaching, system noise, and fiber bending).

For initial preprocessing, I attempted to fit the control signal onto the experimental signal. This process involves subtracting the control from the experimental signal and then normalizing. The attached image illustrates my approach, with subplot 1 showing the control signal, subplot 2 the experimental signal, subplot 3 the control signal fitted onto the experimental signal, and subplot 4 the resulting true signal after subtraction and normalization.

I am considering using a source separation algorithm to isolate the noise from the experimental signal more effectively. While I have the option to utilize the control signal, it's not mandatory for the method I choose. To address photobleaching, I've thought about applying baseline correction for slow detrending. Additionally, I've implemented a low-pass filter with a 6Hz cutoff, given that nearly 100% of the signal frequency resides within the 0-1.5Hz range, making a high-pass filter inapplicable due to the predominance of slow waves.

**I am seeking insights on whether source separation is feasible for this application and if there are recommended strategies or algorithms that could enhance the noise separation process, especially in the context of my current preprocessing steps.**

**[image: Manual fitting preprocessing step]**